# Different OUTPUT when using MERGE statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using `MERGE` to insert or update records into a table:

```
MERGE INTO target 
USING SELECT * FROM @source
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET ...columns...
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT ...columns...
OUTPUT inserted.* INTO @insertedRecord
```

If the above statement performs an update, does the updated record be inserted into the table variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$action` will give you the action type.

`inserted.*` will give you the new values from updates and values for inserted rows.

`deleted.*` will give you old values for updates and values for deleted rows.

You might want to push this into a temp table

```
OUTPUT $action, inserted.*, deleted.*, @source.* into #changes
```

and work with that to get the results you are looking for.

- [merge - msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx)
- [MERGE gives better OUTPUT options - Rob Farley](http://blogs.lobsterpot.com.au/2012/06/12/merge-gives-better-output-options/)
- [Using the Output Clause with T-SQL Merge - David Stein](http://www.made2mentor.com/2013/06/using-the-output-clause-with-t-sql-merge/)

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

The `inserted` psuedotable will handle the new values that go into the table, whether inserted or updated.

The `deleted` pseudotable will handle the old values, whether deleted or updated (for updates, it'd be the previous value).

Even neater: you can reference the source table in a merge as well, e.g. `OUTPUT @source.*` (although you may need an alias on that for it to work).

Comment: Is there a way to output to complete record when updating? (ie unchanged and changed columns)?